# Opening marine phytoplankton NPP data in QGIS

Tags: qgis, noaa, nasa

How can I open these file in QGIS? I am beginner at GIS softwares. My aim is to obtain marine phytoplankton NPP data.

[image]

[image]

These data are available at [oceancolor.gsfc.nasa.gov](https://oceancolor.gsfc.nasa.gov) and [www.nodc.noaa.gov](https://www.nodc.noaa.gov), but QGIS won't open the files as simply as I thought.

Comment: What have you tried?  What errors ensued?  Please show screenshots.

Comment: QGIS 3.14 64 bit is installed on PC and I use Win10. I have downloaded files with NC and hdf extensions. I have got this error message for example: vgpm2019001.hdf not recognized as supported file format.

Comment: How did you open the data file?

Comment: I tried it open as raster file. Earlier I used only shp (vector) and tiff (raster) files and it went without problem to open them.

Comment: There is an immense variety of data available at the two websites you mention.  Please list the *specific* dataset (or its *exact* url) that you tried, so that others might try to load it.

Comment: In case of https://oceancolor.gsfc.nasa.gov Data/Data File Search pattern:A2003001* date:2019. The result of file search is 2186 files. I chose the first one (A2003001.L3b_DAY_CHL.nc).

Comment: In case of https://www.nodc.noaa.gov/ Acces data-> World Ocean Database ->WODselect->Biology search criteria->choose biomass and phytoplankton codes and get inventory->download data